# Python package import issue

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I always struggled with Python package import. I searched the web, but wasn't able to find an appropriate answer.

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
./__init__.py
./packages/
./packages/__init__.py
./packages/package
./packages/package/__init__.py
./packages/package/module.py
```

The module.py source contains only one line:

```
import package
```

If I go to "packages" directory, I am able to import package:

```
>>> import python
>>>
```

If I go to "." directory, I would like to import the module (or the package) as follow:

```
>>> import packages.package.module as module
```

but i'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "vendor/package/module.py", line 1, in <module>
    import package
ImportError: No module named package
```

**What do I need to put in the __init__.py files, so I can do the above import?
More, what do I need to put in ./__init__.py file, so I will able to import my project from ../ directory?**

If possible, I would like to solve this problem without changing the sys.path variable.

Comment: What file you run first? Who starts the whole process?

Comment: Read the documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: `from packages.package import module`

Comment: @alexvassel, I start the process from "." directory, which is the root folder for my project. Basically, I run "python project.py" from ".".

Comment: @ragsagar, that apparently doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the program from . all imports have to be relative to that directory. For your module.py file that means that you have to do

```
import packages.package
```

instead of

```
import package
```

This is because python will use . as the base for all imports that you do in your program. Without a lot of magic it is not possible to import something from a parent directory, so you will have to do an absolute import as shown above.

Comment: It worked, but is there a possibility to do that without modifying the package modules?

Comment: I don't think that is easily possible. But it should not anyway, because you are referring to a parent in a submodule, which could be considered bad design as modules should be as self containing as possible. Nevertheless it happens of course, but only in a self contained project, in which case you  will start it from the same file all the time anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the `import package` in module.py to succeed, the python package `package` must be discoverable. This means it must be on the `PYTHONPATH`. By default this path includes `site-packages` (the directory in which python packages are placed with `easy_install` or `pip`). Further, PYTHONPATH also includes the current working directory.

If you are in `.`, then `.` is placed at the start of your PYTHONPATH. This directory does *not* include a python package called `package`, thus `import package` fails.

You can either move to `./packages` before starting a python interpreter or you can install your package. To do the latter, you'll need a setup.py

Comment: So I can't solve this issue by somehow editing the \__init__.py files?

Comment: You could manipulate sys.path in the packages/__init__.py to add the /packages dir to it

Comment: The sys.path.insert is the solution i'm using right now, but i'm not satisfied with it.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Can you give an example of why you want to import a parent package from a module within it? Are you familiar with installing a python package with setuptools?